# Check if one dataset contains all the records of another dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, performance

I want to find if a dataset A is in the dataset B. That says all the records in A should be there in B. Is there a way in R to check that?

For dataA

```
x1 x2   x3
1  2.3  a
3  1.5  b
```

For dataB

```
x1 x2  x3
0  0.5 a
1  2.3 a
3  1.5 b
2  2   b
```

Comment: `nrow(merge(dataA, dataB, by = names(dataA))) == nrow(dataA)`

Comment: Hi @Phoebe! There are several great answers to this question and for many of your other questions. Is there a reason you havent selected an answer to these questions? You may not be aware of the feature, but there's a little checkmark beside each answer that you can click for the one that best addresses your question. This helps others know the question has been answered and cleans up the site a bit!

Answer (score 5):

You could use `dplyr::setdiff`, which will spit out any rows that are in A but not in B (here, none):

```
dplyr::setdiff(dataA, dataB)

# [1] x1 x2 x3
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

So if you wanted to test that all A is in B:

```
nrow(dplyr::setdiff(dataA, dataB)) == 0

# [1] TRUE
```

Data:

```
dataA <- read.table(text = "x1 x2   x3
1  2.3  a
3  1.5  b", h = TRUE)

dataB <- read.table(text = "x1 x2  x3
0  0.5 a
1  2.3 a
3  1.5 b
2  2   b", h = TRUE)
```

Since there are several great answers here, a quick speed comparison (in case speed is an issue in a large dataset). Scaling up the size of the data frames to 10,000 rows for A and 20,000 for B, it appears `setdiff` is the fastest approach:

```
dataAbig <- data.frame(x1 = 1:1e5,
                       x2 = 1:1e5,
                       x3 = 1:1e5)
dataBbig <- data.frame(x1 = 1:2e5,
                       x2 = 1:2e5,
                       x3 = 1:2e5)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  merge = nrow(merge(dataAbig, dataBbig, by = names(dataAbig))) == nrow(dataAbig),
  anti = nrow(anti_join(dataAbig, dataBbig)) == 0L,
  setdiff = nrow(dplyr::setdiff(dataAbig, dataBbig)) == 0,
  Reduce = all(Reduce(`%in%`, lapply(list(dataAbig, dataBbig), do.call, what = paste)))
)

#    expr         min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval  cld
#   merge   588.51123 669.841215 767.265796 741.498976 835.714448 1173.97895   100 a   
#    anti    43.82270  54.778603  65.541126  61.580967  69.005683  169.14919   100  b  
# setdiff     5.72658   7.365587   8.118022   8.173324   8.946258   10.16296   100   c 
#  Reduce   260.10360 314.980747 364.643984 339.151763 389.427042  821.22359   100    d
```

Answer (score 4):

**BASE R**

The quickest way to see which rows are in both dataframes would be a `merge`

```
merge(dataA,dataB,sort=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`anti_join`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter-joins.html), from the `dplyr` package, is a specific type of filter join that will return all rows in the first data frame *without* a match in the second. If everything is found then this should return an empty data frame:

```r
library(dplyr)
anti_join(dataA, dataB)
# Joining with `by = join_by(x1, x2, x3)`
# [1] x1 x2 x3
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

You can then turn this into a logical value by testing if there are any rows:

```r
# TRUE -> all matched
nrow(anti_join(dataA, dataB)) == 0L
# [1] TRUE
```

By default, this will merge on all common columns between the two data frames.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below, using `do.call` + `paste` and `%in%` + `Reduce`

```
all(Reduce(`%in%`, lapply(list(dataA, dataB), do.call, what = paste)))
```

and benchmark

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    merge = nrow(merge(dataA, dataB, by = names(dataA))) == nrow(dataA),
    setdiff = nrow(dplyr::setdiff(dataA, dataB)) == 0,
    reduce = all(Reduce(`%in%`, lapply(list(dataA, dataB), do.call, what = paste))),
    check = "equal",
    unit = "relative"
)
```

gives

```
Unit: relative
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   merge 21.414414 16.944099 19.105392 14.064943 13.559467 95.456667   100
 setdiff  4.601351  4.270963  4.170636  3.871317  4.052267  3.943333   100
  reduce  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100
```